# ARBOL DE EXPRESION a partir de una operacion igresada por teclado

Tags: java

Podria alguien por favor ayudarme con el codigo en java de como construir un arbol de expresion y calcular su resultado, a partir de una operacion ingresada por teclado, se que se deben utilizar pilas, pero no se donde utilizarlas

```
 public class ArbolExp {

    Nodo raiz;
    Nodo actual;

    public ArbolExp() {
        raiz = null;
        actual = null;
    }

    public boolean Operador(char x) {
        char[] lista = {'+', '-', '/', '*'};
        int cont = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
            if (x == lista[i]) {
                cont += 1;
            }
        }
        if (cont == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void Insertar1(char x) {
        Stack pila = new Stack();
        Nodo nuevo = null;
        Nodo aux = raiz;
        if (x == '(') {
            if (raiz == null) {
                raiz = nuevo;
                pila.push(nuevo);
            } else {
                if (aux.izq == null) {
                    aux.izq = nuevo;
                    pila.push(nuevo);
                    aux = aux.izq;
                } else {
                    aux.der = nuevo;
                    pila.push(nuevo);
                    aux = aux.der;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (Operador(x) == false) {
                if (aux.izq == null) {
                    aux.izq = nuevo;
                } else {
                    aux.der = nuevo;
                    pila.pop();
                }
            } else {
                aux = nuevo;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: saludos y bienvenido; SO en español es un lugar de ayuda mutua para resolver errores de código, que ya lleves avanzado, no para pedir que se te hagan las cosas; a fin de evitar te cierren la pregunta has de editarla y mostrar que llevas

Comment: Te recomiendo usar nashorn para calcular el resultado y así te ahorres hacer un intérprete.

Comment: Entonces el problema es como imprimir lo que tienes en consola?

Comment: NO, es dirigido a que me den una guia de donde utilizar las pilas en este problema